# How to prompt users to enter the correct Department name and to verify it against Active Directory

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I am using the following script in order to get the users from a specific department in AD. The script itself works fine, but I would like to accomplish two things:

1. To make sure that user cannot leave the Dept name blank,
2. To verify that the Dept name exists in Active Directory and if does not exist, than to prompt user to verify the name and to input the correct name.

```
Clear-Host 
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Write-Host "Processing" 
$Dept = Read-Host "Enter the desired department"
$Department = Read-Host -Prompt "Input the desired department name"
if ($Department -eq $null){
    Write-Host "Department cannot be blank, please re-enter the correct department"

$strFilter = "(&(objectCategory=User)(Department=*$Dept*))"
$colResults = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter $strFilter |
              Select-Object -Expand DistinguishedName
```

Comment: How are you going to distribute the script to the users? Since you're using the ActiveDirectory module you need to have this module installed on all machines where this script will run (so you need to install RSAT on all those machines). For scripts that need to run in the user context without the need of RSAT you'll need to dive into .NET (System.DirectoryServices)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract a list of departments from AD like this:

```
$departments = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Property Department |
               Where-Object { $_.Department } |
               Select -Expand Department -Unique
```

With that list you can validate your user input like this:

```
do {
  $Dept = Read-Host "Enter the desired department"
} until ($departments -contains $Dept)
```

Comment: The `$Dept -and` is unnecessary, `Read-Host` will always return a string

Comment: If the user interrupts `Read-Host` by pressing Ctrl-C the variable will retain its previous value (`$null` if it hasn't been assigned a value before). But even then the `-contains` operation would work by itself, so you're right that the additional clause isn't necessary here. Fixed.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. I have another question related to this. If I run your script it times out as follow:                                                   Get-ADUser : This operation returned because the timeout period expired
At line:5 char:15
+ $colResults = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter $strFilter |
+               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ADUser], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : This operation returned because the timeout period expired,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser

Comment: @GeorgeMihailescu If you have a new question: please post a new question.